# CodeIgniter inser/update_batch (probably)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a little problem with my CodeIgniter application.

The code works on apache installed on my laptop, it works on my online server as well, but not on the client's host... ;)

Error info:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given
Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
Line Number: 1113

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
Line Number: 1114

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
Line Number: 1144

A Database Error Occurred
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
```

It seems the problem is about insert_batch & update_batch methods.

Any ideas?

The code is very simple, it works on 2 of 3 servers I've run it. Two functions:

```
public function insert_tabs($fb_user_id, $fanpages) {
        $tabs = array();
        foreach($fanpages as $fanpage) {
            $entry['ta_user_fb_id'] = $fb_user_id;
            $entry['ta_fanpage_id'] = $fanpage['fa_fanpage_id'];
            $entry['ta_text'] = "Put your content here.";

            $tabs[] = $entry;
        }

        return $this->db->insert_batch('tabs', $tabs);
    }
```

And:

```
function set_random_links($entries) {
    $insert = array();
    foreach($entries as $fanpage) {
        $fanpage_id = $fanpage['fa_fanpage_id'];
        $links = $this->get_random_links();

        foreach($links as $link) {
            $entry['lf_fb_fanpage_id'] = $fanpage_id;
            $entry['lf_link_id'] = $link->li_id;

            $insert[] = $entry;
        }
    }

    return $this->db->insert_batch('linksonfanpages', $insert);
}
```

In theory everything is fine.

Comment: share your model's function to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

cross check php version, MySQL version and check whether all files are upload properly.

Most of the time this error occurs due to the version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

First this error means your $fanpages is not an array.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
Line Number: 1144


public function insert_tabs($fb_user_id, $fanpages) {
        $tabs = array();
        if(is_array($fanpages)) {

              foreach($fanpages as $fanpage) {
                  $entry['ta_user_fb_id'] = $fb_user_id;
                  $entry['ta_fanpage_id'] = $fanpage['fa_fanpage_id'];
                  $entry['ta_text'] = "Put your content here.";

                  $tabs[] = $entry;
              }
         }
         if(count($tabs)) return $this->db->insert_batch('tabs', $tabs);
         return -1;
}
```

Also, can we see the source of $fanpages? Because it seems the whole issue if coming from that.